# C# Regex capturing everything

Tags: c#, regex

I want to only have the text inbetween the parenthesis but for some reason it's giving me the whole thing

This is the regex I wrote

`<a href='ete(.+)'>det`

This is the string

```
</td>
<td>
<a href='ete/d1460852470.html'>detailed list #11</a> (20.94KB)
</td>
<td>
392
</td>
<td>
4/17 12:21:10 am
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href='ete/1460845272.html'>ete #5</a> (6.71KB)
</td>
<td>
<a href='ete/d1460845272.html'>detailed list #5</a> (19.76KB)
</td>
<td>
372
</td>
<td>
4/16 10:21:12 pm
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href='ete/1460839272.html'>ete #2</a> (6.62KB)
</td>
<td>
<a href='ete/d1460839272.html'>detailed list #2</a> (19.4KB)
</td>
<td>
366
</td>
<td>
4/16 8:41:12 pm
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href='ete/1460830870.html'>ete #8</a> (6.72KB)
</td>
<td>
<a href='ete/d1460830870.html'>detailed list #8</a> (19.76KB)
</td>
```

I only want the text between `/` and `'`

But that doesn't happen right now. I get back a 3 dimensional array.

This is the code that https://myregextester.com/index.php produces

```
      String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
      Regex re = new Regex(@"<a href='ete(.+)'>det");
      MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
      int mIdx=0;
      foreach (Match m in mc)
       {
        for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
          }
        mIdx++;
      }
```

Comment: You need a [lazy match](https://regex101.com/r/iK7cK2/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble Sorry, lazy match doesn't work, I already tried it. I updated the Question

Comment: We'll need to see the code you're using.  Just the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem, please.

Comment: This works for me. Have you tried `Regex.Matches(<input text>)[n].Groups[1]`?

Comment: @AlanMoore I updated the question with it

Comment: @codran I don;'t; see where I would put it

Comment: @ILovephp123 your program should already be printing what you need when `gIdx` is equal to 1. It will have a leading `/`, but that's because you don't have a `/` in your regex before the capture group, just `ete`.

Comment: @codran Right, but is it not taking longer getting values that it doesn't need? Like why is it also getting the values for when `gIdx` is 0

Comment: @ILovephp123 Group 0 is everything that matches your string. Group 1 is your first capture group. The regex engine doesn't know which group you want. If you want to be pedantic, you can switch to a lookahead and lookbehind, e.g. `(?<=<a href='ete).+(?='>det)`

Comment: @codran That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! Feel free to make an answer so I can select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is in your one of the match groups already - `m[n].Groups[1]` will give you just your capture group. `m[n].Groups[0]` will give you all the text that matched your regular expression, not just your capture group.

If you want to be pedantic, you can switch to a lookahead and lookbehind, e.g. `(?<=<a href='ete).+(?='>det)`, to only match the inner text.

Answer (score 1):

Change the regex to:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"<a href='ete([^']+)'>det");
```

and you should get what you are after.

It's saying match all the characters that are not the closing quote in the group and then match the `'>det` after that.